# motion to the label

Tags: java, label

In my project I have a label i.e sanskarwani samaj
I want this  label to move means I want to give movement to the label is this possible in java tell me how it will work give me the code for that if possible

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

1. display label in initial position
2. sleep(some_second)
3. add x or y position (depends how you want to move your label
4. repaint your label
5. repeat from 2nd step